# Are skill increasing items better than backpacks?

Tags: craft-the-world

No matter how fast dwarves cut down blocks, the majority of time is spent going back and forth with items. Does an increased speed of block breaking ever pay off for forfeiting 1 more item slot?

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since I've played, so I'm not sure if patches have changed anything, but no, I found it was not worth it to give up item slots.

The only exception I could see is if you use the portal spell, and all work is being done near that portal. However, I suspect if you're using the portal spell for such frivolous things, you likely have enough workers that breaking blocks happens near-instantaneously.